# Render the same DIV multiple times and capture each canvas

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rendering, html2canvas

I have a single DIV that can hold many different images based on user input. When the user is done configuring the application, the final output is the images that have been rendered (one-by-one) in the same DIV. To capture the image, I am using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). The problem is that once I start the loop to redraw the images as needed in the div and capture them, only the first image is actually captured each time.

To put it another way, it's as if the showShelf() function in the code below never executes.

```
var exportJSON;
var exportDeviceList;
var renderNumber;
function exportAll()
{
    exportJSON = [];
    exportDeviceList = [];
    renderNumber = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++)
    {
        var elements = devices[i].elements;
        for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++)
        {
            exportDeviceList.push({site: devices[i].site, device: elements[j].id, name: elements[j].tid, config: elements[j].config});
        }
    }
    renderNext();
}

function renderNext()
{
    site = exportDeviceList[renderNumber].site;
    device = exportDeviceList[renderNumber].device;
    config = exportDeviceList[renderNumber].config;
    showShelf(site,device,config);
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("baseImage"), {allowTaint: true}).then(function (canvas)
    {
        exportJSON.push({tid: exportDeviceList[renderNumber].name, image: canvas.toDataURL("image/png")});
        renderNumber++;
        if (renderNumber < exportDeviceList.length)
        {
            renderNext();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer: After performing the `showShelf()` function, I perform a `setTimeout()` function containing the actual `html2canvas()` call and the call to perform the next render.